# JavaFX application with 2 or more fxml files - properties

Tags: java, javafx

I have an app with 3 fxml files. 
The 1st is main window of app and most of work im doing here, but the 2 others fxml files allows me to change some settings and add more records to app.
I made it that 2 small fxml files extends the main file.
Basically:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
@FXML
private TextField txt;
@FXML
private Stage stage;
Symulacja symulacja = new Symulacja();
Promocja promocja = new Promocja();
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    txt.textProperty().bindBidirectional(promocja.getProgKwotyZetonow(), new NumberStringConverter());
    labelProgKwotyZetonow.textProperty().bind(promocja.getProgKwotyZetonow().asString());
}
@FXML
public void zmienUstawienia() {
    symulacja.zmienOkno("FXMLUstawienia.fxml", "Ustawienia");
}
@FXML
public void dodajKlientow() {
    symulacja.zmienOkno("FXMLDodajKlienta.fxml", "Dodawanie");
}
}
```

It's main fxml Controller

```
public class FXMLUstawieniaController extends FXMLDocumentController{

@FXML
private TextField textProgKwota;

@FXML
private Button btnZatwierdzUstawienia;

@FXML
private TextField textProgIlosc;

@FXML
public void zatwierdzUstawienia() {
    promocja.setProgIlosciZetonow(Integer.parseInt(textProgIlosc.getText()));
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    textProgKwota.textProperty().bindBidirectional(promocja.getProgKwotyZetonow(), new NumberStringConverter());
}
}
```

As you see I'm using properties to dynamically change what is showing in `labelProgKwotyZetonow` and `textProgKwota`.

When im not using the 2nd window `txt` and `labelProgKwotyZetonow` works fine, but when I'm initializing 2nd window I always get 0 in TextField and even if I change it this is not changing `labelProgKwotyZetonow`.

It's strange to me because when I'm souting (System.out.println) the value of `promocja.getProgKwotyZetonow()` in some places I get:

In function `initialize` in the 2nd controller - 0.

In function `zmienUstawienia` in 1st controller - the value from `txt`/`labelProgKwotyZetonow`.

In function `zatwierdzUstawienia` in 2nd controller - the value from `textProgKwota`.

Comment: Looks like you expect the `Promocja` of the controller instance of a new controller instance contains the same data as the `Promocja` of a different controller which is probably not the case...

Comment: But doesn't extends provide me with the same instance? I don't declare another `Promocja` in the 2nd controller.

Comment: `String extends Object`, but does that mean the following 2 variables use point to the same instance? `Object o = new Object(); String s = "abcde";` Even using the same type does not make sure the instances are the same, e.g. here it's different `Object o1 = new Object(); Object o2 = new Object();`. If you're using the `fx:controller` attribute to specify the controllers, `FXMLLoader` will always create a new instance of the controller when loading the fxml. You should probably take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml

Comment: thx I will try it